# UberRUSH not available at checkout on Shopify

Tags: uber-api

We are having a current issue with UberRUSH not showing at checkout for our local customers.

Are there any known issues right now with the Shopify integration?

Thank you,
Ben
www.sportique.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be a programming related question, and Stack Overflow is not Uber support.

Comment: No problem. Uber directed me here to get help on this issue. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

There was an outage earlier with the Uber API. All is now resolved, but you may have been impacted.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.